# can a scrapy parser call another parser and send response without a new request?

Tags: parsing, scrapy

I am new in using scrapy. Could anyone please tell how I can make the following code work? In my spider, it stop at the parse1.

Thank you!

```
def parse1(self,response):
    response.meta['addedKey']=addedData1
    self.parse_all(response)

def parse2(self,response):
    response.meta['addedKey']=addedData2
    self.parse_all(response)

def parse_all(self,response):
    yield FormRequest(self.url,formdata={'key':response.meta['addedKey']},callback = self.someparser)
```

Comment: thank you for reminding.

Comment: `callback=self.someparser`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to yield from the generator, for `parse1`:

```
def parse1(self,response):
    response.meta['addedKey']=addedData1
    for item in parse_all(response):  # parse_all is a generator
        yield item
```